# lenovo ideapad gaming 3-ad linux support

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia, laptop, intel

is lenovo ideapad gaming 3-ad
with core i 7 - 11 gen

16gig ddr 4 ram

and
nvidia GeForce rtx 3050 ti

supports ubuntu 21 and another linux distros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : high probability

Real answer:

I guess here is a semi-gaming like setup of your PC.

Until, you don't give enough details about motherboard & BIOS setup and so on, the probability of Linux X86_64  will run on it is very very high.

You choose Ubuntu, so here again I can confirm that.

If you have limited performances on the Graphical card for your recent games, just install the proprietary version of the Nvidia driver to increase performances.

I can also confirm you just have to choose a X86_64 linux distro to run it on your machine. If you doubt, you can use a Linux USBstick to test the distribution before choosing and installing it.